# Filtering rows in R by using string and dplyr approach

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, rows

I am new in R and try to filter a whole row with all data by a string. I want to save the filtered rows as a new variable or dataframe. I want to use the library(dplyr)
My dataframe "Anatomy" looks like this:

```
  Species Value1 Value2
1 Species1      1     NA
2 Species2      2     NA
3 species3      3     NA
```

I tried now:

```
Species1<-data.frame(filter(Anatomy, Species == "Species1"))
```

But my output is always only the headers.

```
Species Value1 Value2
```

Could you help me please?

Comment: `Species1 <- filter(Anatomy, Species == "Species1")` or `Species1 <- Anatomy[Anatomy$Species == "Species1", ]`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about how to use `dplyr::filter()` to accomplish what you want, but you can simply do the following to get only the Species1 data

```
new_df <- df[df$Species=='Species1', ]
```